# Starlette JSONResponse into Pydantic parse_obj_as

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, starlette

Working with fastapi and having a function that returns created JSONResponse. My goal is to create custom 200 response and put it into Pydantic `parse_obj_as` with an expected BaseModel.

Is there a way of getting back the JSONResponse data? Or there any workaround? Thanks!

```
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse


def func():
    model_id = 0

    resp = JSONResponse(
        {"detail": f"Model {model_id} created", "HTTPStatusCode": 200},
       status_code=200,
    )
    return parse_obj_as(<here I need resp data>, MyBaseModel)
```

BaseModel:

```
from pydantic.types import PositiveInt
from __future__ import annotations, generator_stop
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyBaseModel(BaseModel):
    """
    Docstring
    """

    detail: str
    HTTPStatusCode: PositiveInt
```

Comment: Could you please share `MyBaseModel`

Comment: @PouyaEsmaeili Added the BaseModel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parse_obj_as` requires dictionary input. Body of the response object is accessible via `response.body`. And you need to transform bytes type of body to dictionary by calling `json.loads()`.

```
import json
from pydantic.types import PositiveInt
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel, parse_obj_as


class MyBaseModel(BaseModel):
    """
    Docstring
    """
    detail: str
    HTTPStatusCode: PositiveInt


def func():
    model_id = 0
    resp = JSONResponse(
        {"detail": f"Model {model_id} created", "HTTPStatusCode": 200}, status_code=200,
    )
    return parse_obj_as(MyBaseModel, json.loads(resp.body))


ret = func()
```

And this is the return value:

```
detail='Model 0 created' HTTPStatusCode=200
```

Comment: Working great mate, thanks a lot for help!